# Javascript quiz not going on to next quiz item

Tags: javascript

I have a quiz that should move on to the next question once you select an answer but at the moment my code doesn't work and it allows the user to select multiple answers, without anything happening afterwards.

Once they finish the last question their result should be displayed to them.

```js
document.getElementById("beginquiz").addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

function startQuiz() {
  document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";
}

var answerData = {
  "p": 0,
  "vp_w": 0,
  "vp_e": 0,
  "vp_a": 0,
  "vp_s": 0
};

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = buttonClicked;
}

function buttonClicked(buttonNext) {
  var target = answer.target; //1. 'this' is parent, need target
  console.log(target);
  //get the current element's data-score value
  var selectedType = target.dataset.score; //2. score is the value
  //increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
  console.log(selectedType);
  answerData[selectedType]++;
  //Hide the current question div
  this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  //Work out what the next question div is
  var nextQuestion = this.parentElement.dataset.next;
  //Display the next question element
  console.log(nextQuestion);
  document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
  if(document.getElementById(nextQuestion))
   document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
 else
   printResult();
}

function calculateResult (answerData){
  var highest = Math.max(total_points.p, total_points.vp_s, total_points.vp_e, total_points.vp_w, total_points.vp_a);
  var result;
   for (var i in total_points) {
     if (total_points.hasOwnProperty(i)){
       if (total_points[i] === highest){
         result = i;
        }
      }
    }
switch(result) {
     case 'p':
      result = 'President';
      break;
     case 'vp_w':
      result = 'Vice-President Welfare';
      break;
     case 'vp_e':
      result = 'Vice-President Education';
      break;
     case 'vp_s':
      result = 'Vice-President Sports';
      break;
     case 'vp_a':
      result = 'Vice-President Activities';
      break;
     default:
      break;
    }

    return result;
};
function printResult() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<h2>You are: '+result+'</h2>';
}
```

```css
.question,
#result {
  display: none;
}

.button li {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button li:hover {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  background-color: #555;
}

#intro,
.question,
#result {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#beginquiz:hover {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro">
  <button id="beginquiz">Start the quiz</button>
</div>

<form name="quiz" method="post" name="buttons" id="quiz" onsubmit="return false">

<div  class="question"  id="q1" data-next="q2">
<li><div>What is?</div></li>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="p">Answer 1<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_a">Answer 2<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_s">Answer 3<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_w">Answer 4<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_e">Answer 5<hr>
    </div>

<div  class="question" id="q2" data-next="q3">
<li><div>What is?</div></li>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="p">Answer 1<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_a">Answer 2<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_s">Answer 3<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_w">Answer 4<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_e">Answer 5<hr>
    </div>
    
<div  class="question" id="q3" data-next="q4">
<li><div id="q3" data-next="q4">What is?</div></li>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="p">Answer 1<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_a">Answer 2<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_s">Answer 3<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_w">Answer 4<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_e">Answer 5<hr>
    </div>
    
<div  class="question" id="q4">
<li><div>What is?</div></li>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="p">Answer 1<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_a">Answer 2<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_s">Answer 3<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_w">Answer 4<br>
    <input id="answer" type="radio" data-score="vp_e">Answer 5<hr>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="result">
  <h2>You are:</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your buttonclicked function you had some errors on how you were getting the elements.  Here is the updated function.  There was another error in the printResults that there was no call to display the results div.  You also are not calling the calulateResults functions.

```
function buttonClicked(buttonNext) {    
 //var target = answer.target; //1. 'this' is parent, need target
 var target;
 for(i=answer.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  if(answer[i].checked == true){
     target = answer[i];
     break;
   }
 }
 console.log(target);
 //get the current element's data-score value
 var selectedType = target.dataset.score; //2. score is the value
 //increase the selected answer's 'type' by 1
 console.log(selectedType);
 answerData[selectedType]++;
 //Hide the current question div
 console.log(target.parentElement.id);
 //this.parentElement.style.display = "none";
 target.parentElement.style.display = "none"
 //Work out what the next question div is
 var nextQuestion = target.parentElement.dataset.next;
 //Display the next question element
 console.log(nextQuestion);
 //document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
 if(document.getElementById(nextQuestion))
    document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block";
 else
  printResult();
}
```

You needed to use a for loop to get the target answer in the array of answers.  I decremented the loop to get the last answered question.  The other change is to how you got the parent ID.  With this.parentElement it was coming back with the body due to the this element was focused on the form, the element the clcik event was fired on.  The last thing I commented out the extra document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block"; before the check.